# Instant Rebuild & View of LaTeX Buffer in AUCTeX

Tags: emacs, auctex, viewers, build-system

Is there a command in latex-mode when using Emacs+AUCTeX that combines `TeX-command-buffer` and `TeX-view` into one single instant redisplay command?

I don't see the point in having two separate key combos for this operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't see the point in having two separate key combos for this operation.

After a `*tex` run one can run `*tex` another time, or the bibliography processor or the `makeindex` tool or something else, before viewing the document.  Conversely, you may want to view the document just after a single run of `*tex`, without running `*tex` again or the bibliography processor or `makeindex`, etc, even if they are actually needed.

Thus the point is that AUCTeX doesn't know what you want to do after a single run of `*tex`, but nothing prevents you from setting up a function (with an associated key binding) which fires up the document viewer after a run of `*tex`.

Probably, `TeX-texify` is the feature you are looking for: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TN#toc8

Comment: I just use latexmk in pvc mode, all i have to do is save, then the rest is automatic

Comment: @daleif I have `latexmk` in `TeX-command-list`, too, but most of the time I prefer to run `LaTeX` just once and see the result.  But this is a matter of taste `;-)`.